# Google end point returns JSON for long data type in quotes

Tags: json, google-app-engine, gwt, google-cloud-endpoints, resty-gwt

I am using Google cloud end point for my rest service. I am consuming this data in a GWT web client using RestyGWT.

I noticed that cloud end point is automatically enclosing a long datatype in double quotes which is causing an exception in RestyGWT when I try to convert JSON to POJO.

Here is my sample code.

```
@Api(name = "test")
public class EndpointAPI {

@ApiMethod(httpMethod = HttpMethod.GET,  path = "test")
public Container test() {
    Container container = new Container();

    container.testLong =  (long)3234345;
    container.testDate = new Date();
    container.testString = "sathya";
    container.testDouble = 123.98;
    container.testInt = 123;                
    return container;
}
public class Container {
    public long testLong;
    public Date testDate;
    public String testString;
    public double testDouble;
    public int testInt;
}
```

}

This is what is returned as JSON by cloud end point. You can see that testLong is serialized as "3234345" rather than 3234345.

[image]

I have the following questions.
(1) How can I remove double quotes in long values ?
(2) How can I change the string format to "yyyy-MMM-dd hh:mm:ss" ?

Regards,
Sathya

Comment: You don't want to "remove the quotes": not all long values can be expressed as a JS Number, and RestyGWT probably parses the JSON into a JS object (`JSON.parse()` or `eval()`). No, you actually want RestyGWT to properly use `Long.parseLong()` (don't know how to do it, if at all possible; I don't know RestyGWT). As for the date, why would you want to *not* use a standard format?

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't find a way yet how to make restygwt parse long correctly. Same issue with date formats - restygwt is throwing exception when deserializing.

Answer (score 1):

What version of restyGWT are you using ? Did you try 1.4 snapshot ? 
I think this is the code (1.4) responsible for parsing a long in restygwt, it might help you :

```
 public static final AbstractJsonEncoderDecoder<Long> LONG = new AbstractJsonEncoderDecoder<Long>() {

    public Long decode(JSONValue value) throws DecodingException {
        if (value == null || value.isNull() != null) {
            return null;
        }
        return (long) toDouble(value);
    }

    public JSONValue encode(Long value) throws EncodingException {
        return (value == null) ? getNullType() : new JSONNumber(value);
    }
};

 static public double toDouble(JSONValue value) {
    JSONNumber number = value.isNumber();
    if (number == null) {
        JSONString val = value.isString();
        if (val != null){
            try {
                return Double.parseDouble(val.stringValue());
            }
            catch(NumberFormatException e){
                // just through exception below
            }
        }
        throw new DecodingException("Expected a json number, but was given: " + value);
    }
    return number.doubleValue();
}
```